# Database index VS full table scan of memory index

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing, database-design, sphinx

I want to create an app like (for example) Tinder. So I must be able to list all users around me that correspond also to some criteria (age, religion, etc.).

Actually all the users are stored in mongoDB but mongoDB look like very bad to do such query, example I do

```
db.runCommand( { dropDatabase: 1 } )

db.createCollection("users"); 

db.users.createIndex( { "locs.loc" : "2dsphere" } )


function randInt(n) { return parseInt(Math.random()*n); }
function randFloat(n) { return Math.random()*n; }

for(var j=0; j<10; j++) {  
  print("Building op "+j);
  var bulkop=db.users.initializeOrderedBulkOp() ;
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    bulkop.insert(    
      {
        locs: [
          {
            loc : { 
              type: "Point", 
              coordinates: [ randFloat(180), randFloat(90) ] 
            }
          },
          {
            loc : { 
              type: "Point", 
              coordinates: [ randFloat(180), randFloat(90) ] 
            }
          }
        ]
      }  
    )
  };
  print("Executing op "+j);
  bulkop.execute();
}
```

then

```
db.runCommand(
   {
     geoNear: "users",
     near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 73.9667, 40.78 ] },
     spherical: true,
     query: { category: "xyz" }
   }
)
```

and it's took me **4 min** to return

```
   "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
   "results" : [ ],
   "stats" : {
           "nscanned" : 10018218,
           "objectsLoaded" : 15000000,
           "maxDistance" : 0,
           "time" : 219873
   },
   "ok" : 1
```

So definitively I must use something else **but what** ? I m quite sure I need a **memory index** like [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) (so simply store all the records in memory and do on each query a full scan of all the rows). Actually It's work pretty well but sphinx index is oriented to index **text document** and I m not sure it's will fit well my need.

Comment: Hi loki; can I ask if you've investigated why this query is running slowly? For example, do other types of geospatial query also run slow; or have you considered making a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/#create-a-compound-index-with-2dsphere-index-key) on the _category_ and _loc_ fields?

Answer (score 1):

In Sphinx / Manticore the search over 1M documents will be much faster. On my server (not very powerful one) it takes ~100ms and the index takes ~16M of RAM and ~31M of disk space.

```
mysql> select id, geodist(lat,lng,73.9667,40.78, {in=deg,out=km}) dist, lat, lng from idx where dist < 5;
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| id     | dist     | lat       | lng       |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| 456688 | 4.311642 | 74.005157 | 40.793140 |
| 679960 | 2.206543 | 73.979790 | 40.726372 |
| 904809 | 3.339423 | 73.936790 | 40.783146 |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.10 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from idx;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1000000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)

[snikolaev@dev01 ~]$ ls -lah idx_1m.sp*
-rw------- 1 snikolaev snikolaev  16M Apr 12 05:17 idx_1m.spa
-rw------- 1 snikolaev snikolaev 6.7M Apr 12 05:17 idx_1m.spd
-rw------- 1 snikolaev snikolaev    1 Apr 12 05:17 idx_1m.spe
-rw------- 1 snikolaev snikolaev  334 Apr 12 05:17 idx_1m.sph
-rw------- 1 snikolaev snikolaev 7.8M Apr 12 05:17 idx_1m.spi
-rw------- 1 snikolaev snikolaev    0 Apr 12 05:17 idx_1m.spk
-rw------- 1 snikolaev snikolaev    0 Apr 12 05:17 idx_1m.spl
-rw------- 1 snikolaev snikolaev    0 Apr 12 05:17 idx_1m.spm
-rw------- 1 snikolaev snikolaev    1 Apr 12 05:17 idx_1m.spp
-rw------- 1 snikolaev snikolaev    1 Apr 12 05:17 idx_1m.sps
```

So I don't see any problem with using Sphinx / Manticore in your case:

- if you prefer batch data loading xmlpipe/csvpipe will allow you load
  data from mongodb easily
- if you need to load data real time it's also possible via RealTime indexes
- and the performance/resource consumption is
  on decent level

Be aware though it's not pure in-memory solution, i.e. your data once indexed will be stored on disk, the attributes though (langitude and longitude in your case) are always kept in memory for better performance.

Another option (if you're looking for MORE in-memory solution) would be RediSearch which also can do geo search - https://redis.io/commands/georadius
I'm not an expert in that so can't say whether it's faster than Sphinx / Manticore or not.

Comment: thanks manticore! but like sphinx i thinks Manticore is mostly oriented full-text search engine. How in manticore we can update the index ?

Comment: @loki You probably mean attributes update, not text. Then it can be done like this:

mysql> update idx set lat = 75.028214, lng = 41.751846 where id = 41219;

Update by expression is also possible. The updates stay in memory by default. "FLUSH ATTRIBUTES" command will sync the updates to disk or they can be synced once a while (there's option rt_flush_period in config)